# Android resource diectory name to string for WavFile usage

Tags: android, string, wav, getresource

I am using the Wave tools downloaded from here: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

To begin to read a wav file in my res/raw directory I have done the following in a sub class which extends my main activity.

```
WavFile wavFile = WavFile.openWavFile(new File(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xsp11_10db).toString()));
```

Where context is defined as:

```
Context context;
```

The first line returns a NullPointerException, so it seems the type of class WaveFile (wavfile) returns null. Which brings to question the way I define the File string:

```
new File(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xsp11_10db).toString());
```

I know it is a crude way to obtain the resource wavfile "xsp11_10db", but I am unaware of any other methods to access the file. I tried with URI's but the directory was not found.

Does anyone know of a better way to read the wave file from resource, or what is causing my null pointer exception.

Any help would be appreciated, thankyou in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Wav API you are using does not support `InputStream`, and only accepts File as input. This is understandable, because most likely they use `RandomAccessFile` for implementation.

You probably thought that `.openRawResource(...).toString()` would give you file name, but that is not true. It will just call `.toString()` on `InputStream` returned from `openRawResource(...)`. Which is not what you want.

The solution is to open `InputStream` using `openRawResource()` and copy data to a new file on SD card yourself. And then use that file for Wav API you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I am implementing your advice. However, even when I use
`code`InputStream stream = new DataInputStream((context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xsp11_10db)));

It seems `code`context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xsp11_10db)

Still returns a null. When I extend my main activity what is the correct way to define context. Perhaps context isn't linking to correct context.